# Found a twisted python tutorial that is outdated, does anyone know how to get the code working?

Tags: python, server, twisted

I am trying to get a chatroom working using a tutorial I found online with the twisted module in python, but I got this error message from the Chrome Network Inspector: "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404"
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Python version is 3.8.3

Chrome Version is 84.0.4147.89

I am on Windows 10 Home Version 1909 OS Build 18363.959

https://github.com/github-is-stupid/pyserver

Tutorial

https://pawelmhm.github.io/python/websockets/2016/01/02/playing-with-websockets.html

```
Pip freeze output is this
attrs==19.3.0
autobahn==20.7.1
Automat==20.2.0
cffi==1.14.1
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==3.0
hyperlink==19.0.0
idna==2.10
incremental==17.5.0
pycparser==2.20
PyHamcrest==2.0.2
six==1.15.0
Twisted==20.3.0
txaio==20.4.1
websockets==8.1
zope.interface==5.1.0
```

My terminal message is this :

```
2020-07-29 17:02:41-0700 [-] "127.0.0.1" - - [30/Jul/2020:00:02:41 +0000] "GET /ws HTTP/1.1" 404 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537
.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Please post your code here

Comment: A handshake is an agreement between the requester and the server. That is all I know.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this code. It works on mac (osx catalina) with chrome 83.0.4103.116. Not sure what is the issue with windows 10. I am on python 2.7.16 with Twisted==20.3.0.

Added:
I am able to reproduce this problem using python 3.8.5. So I think this is a version issue. The original example was intended to python 2.7.